# Why is r-caret's preProcess object so big?

Tags: r, r-caret

I have a data.frame with the data (about 161 MB). When I create caret's preProcess object:

```
object = preProcess(data, method="YeoJohnson")
```

It takes about 934 MB. Why is it so big, while it even doesn't store transformed data?

Comment: Did you look into the source, Luke?

Comment: @DavidArenburg I haven't looked in data scource of caret, but it's good idea. It looks like bug, because almost all space is taken by object$yj which is list of lists. And it constains mostly nulls 
'> object$yj[1][1:10]
$a_total_balance_12m
Estimated transformation parameters 
        Y1 
0.05921155 

$<NA>
NULL

$<NA>
NULL

$<NA>
NULL

$<NA>
NULL

$<NA>
NULL

$<NA>
NULL

$<NA>
NULL

$<NA>
NULL

$<NA>
NULL'